# Spark operator vs spark submit - how to choose which one to use?

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

There are two ways to run spark application on Kubernetes.

1. Use spark-submit with `k8s://` master URL.
2. Use [spark-on-k8s-operator](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-on-k8s-operator). With the benefit of CRD in spark operator, we could have declarative management of spark pods using configuration files (YAML).

How do I choose between them in production that running 1000+ spark workloads on Kubernetes?

Any pros and cons of using a spark operator?

Answer (score 4):

Pros of `spark-on-k8s-operator`:

- creating a k8s deployment of the Spark Operator will spawn pods of `SparkApplication` type and spawn driver and executor pods.
- Includes a Prometheus metrics exporter
- Simplifies application development and management to a YAML file   * It can be scheduled using `ScheduledSparkApplication`

Cons of `spark-submit`

- creates naked pods, more [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/overview/#naked-pods-vs-replicasets-deployments-and-jobs)
- configurations able to be scattered throughout:
  `spark-submit`, `SessionBuilder`, Scala or python code, and k8s.
- requires additional scheduler

TL;DR - Use `spark-on-k8s-operator`